# Redux Form Custom Component Always Unintentionally Submit the Form When Changing

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I created a custom redux form component of this react-date-range (https://github.com/Adphorus/react-date-range ). This component somehow unintentionally submits the form when I change the data.

[image: Form events]

this is my implementation of component

```
import React from 'react';

import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main style file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; // theme css file
import { DateRange } from 'react-date-range';

class RenderDateRange extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const initValues = props.input && props.input.value || {};

    this.state = {
      startDate: initValues.startDate || new Date(),
      endDate: initValues.endDate || new Date(),
      key: 'selection',
      showDatePicker : false
    }
  }

  constructEvent(selection) {
    return {
      startDate: selection.startDate.getTime(),
      endDate: selection.endDate.getTime()
    }
  }

  handleChange(payload) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      ...payload.selection
    });

    this.props.input.onChange(this.constructEvent(payload.selection));
  }

  render() {
    const {input} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <DateRange
          {...input}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          ranges={[this.state]}
          className={'PreviewArea'}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RenderDateRange;
```

and this is how my form is about

```
<form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field name="eventDate" component={RenderDateRange} />
    <button className="btn btn-default btn-save" disabled={submitting || pristine || invalid}>
      Save
    </button>
</form>
```

and this is the component that contains the form like:
   render() {
        const _props = this.props;

```
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 content-container">
          {this.renderNotification()}
          <NewCustomerForm { ..._props } onSubmit={_props.createCustomer.bind(this, _props.lang)}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

anyone has a clue what is wrong with my implementation?

========================================================

I also have tried to remove this.props.input and onChange from props of DateRange and it still submits the form.

```
<DateRange
  ranges={[this.state]}
  className={'PreviewArea'}
/>
```

[image: Form events without onChange]

Comment: can you also post the component that contains the form

Comment: @seethrough hi, i've put the component above